# How to get unmasked value from MaskedTextField - FluentUI

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

I'm using MaskedTextField component from Microsoft FluentUI library. I'm trying to get unmasked value from the component but no success. I tried both controlled component approach by passing value to props, and uncontrolled component approach by passing defaultvalue to props; and inspected the component properties in OnChange event handler but I found no property that stores the unmasked value.

Am I doing the right way? is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the imperative API, it's possible to get the unmasked value. One important caveat from the docs:

> The value of all filled format characters or **undefined if not all format characters are filled**

Here's an example that pulls the value when a button is clicked:

```jsx
const TextFieldBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState("");
  const [fetchedValue, setFetchedValue] = React.useState("");
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const fetchValue = React.useCallback(() => {
    setFetchedValue(ref.current.value);
  }, [setFetchedValue, ref]);
  const obj = {val, fetchedValue};
  return (
    <>
   <MaskedTextField ref={ref} label="With input mask" mask="m\ask: (999) 999 - 9999" value={val} onChange={(_, theVal) => setVal(theVal)} />
<button onClick={fetchValue}>Get value</button>
   <pre>{JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
```

([full working example](https://codepen.io/jdh-msft/pen/abdbXEm?editors=0010))

If this API doesn't meet your needs, it's probably worth [opening an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/new/choose), as there are several straightforward ways this could be improved.